# Pattern not match error in fluentd while tailing json file

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, fluentd

I have installed fluentd logger and I want it to monitor the logs of my python code. The logs are the json logs and looks like below:

```
{
    "FileNo": 232,
    "FileClass": "timitry",
    "FileLevel": "24",
    "DataCount": 5,
    "Data": {
        "User1": <Username>,
        "User2": <Username>,
        "User3": <Username>,
        "User4": <Username>,
        "User5": <Username>"
    },
    "time": "2018-05-14T05:33:02.071793"
}
```

This is updated every 5mins. I need to write a fluentd input plugin for it so that it can read the new json data and the publish it to `elastic search`. I dont really know which input plugin to use here but I used `tail` which give me below errors:

```
2018-05-14 05:31:04 +0000 [warn]: #0 pattern not match: "    \"FileClass\": \"timitry\","
```

This is same for all the data. Can anyone please suggest me how can I resolve this issue. Below is the configuration file:

```
<source>
  @type tail
  format json
  path /home/user/Documents/logs/file_log.json
  tag first
</source>

<match first*>
  @type elasticsearch
  hosts 192.168.111.456:9200
  user <username>
  password <password>
</match>
```

I have seen others using `regex` and other formats. Do I also need to use it. How can I use the logs generated by python code to be used by fluentd and publish it to `elastic search`.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get past this?  I am having exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try too remove the wildcard after the first in your match directive ?
Like :

```
<match first>
 @type elasticsearch
 hosts 192.168.111.456:9200
 user <username>
 password <password>
</match>
```